# unable to access array of pointers to characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 256
int main() {
    int partsize, len = 0;
    int j, k, n, i = 0;
    char* str1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    // char *str2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    // int *count=(int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str1);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str2);
    //  printf("%s %s",str1,str2);
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    char** p = (char**)calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    len = strlen(str1);
    if (len % n != 0) {
        printf("Sorry");
    } else {
        k = 0;
        p = temp;
        partsize = len / n;
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            *(temp + k) = str1[j];
            if ((j + 1) % partsize == 0) {
                *(temp + k) = "\n";
                p++;
                p = temp + k + 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s", *(*(p + i)));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to divide the string into n equal parts.But when i run this code i do not get any output.I think the problem is with the pointer to array of pointers to character.Please help.

Comment: Have you tried `scanf("%s",str1);`? ...and then flushing the input buffer with `do { c = getchar(); } while (c != '\n');` after each `scanf`?

Comment: No, but I cant think that is not the reason.Is everything fine with the declaration of pointer to pointer to char?

Comment: `p=temp;` is wrong, `p` is a `char**` and `temp` is a `char*`

Comment: What is it with all these `*(thing + foo)` these days ? Some anti-bracket conspiracy ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can do it in a more simple fashion allocating all needed memory dynamically. This allows you to handle any length string. Also, note the use of `getline`. It provides the advantage of returning the length of the string read (including the null-terminating char). The comments inline explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    size_t partsize = 0;
    size_t end = 0;
    ssize_t read = 0;
    ssize_t len = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char *ptr = NULL;
    char *str1 = NULL;

    printf ("\n  Please enter a string (of n parts)   : ");
    if ((read = getline (&str1, &end, stdin)) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "\nError: str1 returned no characters.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("  Enter the number of parts for string : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf ("\n");

    /* create n char pointers to hold equal parts of str1 */
    char** p = calloc (n, sizeof(char*));
    len = read - 1;     /* null-terminator added by getline */
    partsize = len / n;
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf ("  partsize: %zd, n: %d, len: %zd, str1: %s\n", partsize, n, len, str1);
#endif /* DEBUG */

    if (len % n != 0) {
        printf("Sorry");
    } else {

        ptr = str1;                         /* assign ptr to str1 */

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {           /* for each part      */
            p[i] = strndup (ptr, partsize); /* dup partsize chars */
            ptr += partsize;                /* advance pointer    */
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("  p[%d]: %s\n", i, *(p + i));
        }

        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**build:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/captr captr.c
```

**build with DEBUG (if desired):**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/captr captr.c -DDEBUG
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/captr

Please enter a string (of n parts)   : 012345678901234567890123456789
Enter the number of parts for string : 3

p[0]: 0123456789
p[1]: 0123456789
p[2]: 0123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

You have various problems in the code:

- `k` is never updated in the loop.
- `printf` would not stop printing when `\n` is encounter, only when NULL (`\0`) is.
- You are incrementing the pointers (specifically `p` in the loop) and not restarting to the initial position to print the result (in the last loop you are printing with `p` in the updated position).

Code (Tested GCC 4.9.0), in this code i try to change as little as possible of your code. See the improve version for better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 256
int main() {
    int partsize, len = 0;
    int j, k, n, i = 0;
    char** p;
    char* str1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    // char *str2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    // int *count=(int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str1);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str2);
    //  printf("%s %s",str1,str2);
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    char** pp = (char**)calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    len = strlen(str1);
    if (len % n != 0) {
        printf("Sorry");
    } else {
        k = 0;
        p = pp;
        *p = temp;
        partsize = len / n;
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++, k++) {
            *(temp + k) = str1[j];
            if ((j + 1) % partsize == 0) {
                k++;
                *(temp + k) = '\0';
                p++;
                *p = temp + k + 1;
            }
        }
        p = pp;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", *(p + i));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the improve code:

- There is no need to copy the input string to another buffer. In this example think in `temp` as `p` in the original code.
- You need only to save the positions of split and print the characters between.

Improve Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 256
int main() {
    int n, i, j, k;

    char* str1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str1);
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int len = strlen(str1);
    if (len % n != 0) {
        printf("Sorry");
    } else {
        int partsize = len / n;
        char** temp = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * partsize);
        k = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < len; j += partsize, k++) {
            temp[k] = &str1[j];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%.*s\n", partsize, temp[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input for Test:

```
123456789101112
3
```

Output obtained with both sources:

```
12345
67891
01112
```

Compiled with: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o test.exe test.c`

Comment: I obtain the same output with the two versions of the code, tested with GCC 4.9.0 in Windows XP and Windows 8.1. In what platform are you testing and what are the output or problem presented with the code.

Comment: The improved code is working but not the one in which you made some changes.I am using Dev C++.